# Custom Drag n Drop webpart in sharepoint Edit Mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, drag-and-drop, edit-mode-panel

Can anyone help me in SPFx online?

I am creating a custom web-part in which I am using HTML drag and drop API in edit mode. Somehow my drag and drop functionality is working if used it in preview mode but not in Edit mode.

I want to implement that in Edit mode. Whenever I drag a div in Edit mode SPFx default drag and drop feature gets activated and override my custom drag and drop functionality.

Does anyone knows how to override default one and let the custom drag n drop function works?

Comment: Could you mention that, are you making the webparts draggable or the content of webpart?

Comment: I am making a content of web-part draggable.

Comment: Could you share your code. I have used https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reactjs-implement-drag-and-drop-feature-without-using-external-libraries-ad8994429f1a/
and it's working fine for me.

Comment: I have developed kanban view using reactjs git repo: https://gitlab.com/palash924332931/spfxkanbanview

Image: https://prnt.sc/qhg9vg

Comment: @PalashKantiBachar, I tried [react-drag-sortable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-drag-sortable) and it worked. Thank you